# Convert a range of lists to sub list and store them in an list of type linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I already have a list type Integer with values in it and I want to test sequentially from index zero if the sum of one range of elements satisfy a particular value then copy this range in an list and store it in a list of linkedlist. Then again test sequentially but now from the following index of the previous range, so if the previous range was index 0 to index 9 then start at index 10, and repeat the process until the last index.

```
List<Integer> arrayB = new LinkedList<Integer>(); //this is the array with values in it

List<LinkedList> p = new LinkedList<LinkedList>();// this is the array of arrays  

List<Integer> arrayA = new LinkedList<Integer>();// this is the range or the sub list of arrayB

public void function(int n)// suppose that n = 6 and arrayB have these value {1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2}
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int w : arrayB)
    {
        count = w + count;
        arrayA.add(w);
        if(count == n)
        {
            count = 0;
            p.add((LinkedList) arrayA);
            arrayA.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code fail when I call method clear in arrayA so is there any alternative to code with this logic regardless of the data structure used?

Comment: That's an extremely long first sentence.  You lost us at "if the sum of one range..".

Comment: You lost me even earlier.  About when you start calling a `LinkedList` and array of arrays.  In Java arrays have a distinct type from lists.  If you call a "list" an "array", or vice versa, the result will be that we figure out when "array" means Java array or Java `List`.

Comment: @ergonaut i have edited the post it is the sum of one range of elements if you see the code for example the elements in arrayB has the elements {1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2} so the sum of the first 3 elements is 6 which satisfy the condition (count == n) so the range would be index 0 to index 2.

Comment: @StephenC I have edited the question in terms of generic collection instead of arrays however this question does not limited the use of arrays in any alternative code for the answer

Comment: What do you mean by "range of elements"?  Range in the mathematical sense?  Sublist?  Something else?

Comment: @StephenC in this case range is the set of elements satisfying the condition

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Is it a sublist / subsequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same list reference arrayA every time you add a sub list into p, every list element in p is pointing to the same arrayA . So when you call arrayA.clear(); You clear all the list elements in p.

To correct that, you need to create a new list object when you add a sublist to arrayA:

```
public static void function(int n)// suppose that n = 6 and arrayB have these value {1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2}
{
    int count = 0;

    LinkedList<Integer> subList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int w : arrayB) {
        count = w + count;
        subList.add(w);
        if (count == n) {
            count = 0;
            p.add((LinkedList) subList); // p is adding a new list reference every time
            subList = new LinkedList<>(); // create a new list object, subList points to a new list object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the answer I was hoping for it is working perfectly fine I had to just changed one line of code thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the problem is the following:
There exists an array from which you would like to extract a certain range of values given that they satisfy some criteria. In this case, the criterion is that the range evaluates to some sum. Once this has been completed, you would like to repeat the process until all of the values in the original data-structure have been exhausted. 
I will assume that your original data-structure is an array of integers, and that your resulting data-structure is a linkedlist of integer arrays.

One way to do it may be to keep a global counter that keeps track of the current index of the original array, such as something like the following:

```
int[] originalArray = {//list of numbers separated by commas};
LinkedList<Integer[]> resultingList = new LinkedList<>();
int currentIndex = 0;

public static void function(int totalSum) {
    int currentSum = 0;
    int initialIndex = currentIndex;
    while((currentSum != totalSum) && (currentIndex < (originalArray.length - 1))) {
        if(currentSum + initialArray[currentIndex] <= totalSum) {
            currentSum += initialArray[currentIndex];
            currentIndex++;
        } 
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(currentSum = totalSum) {
        int[] arrayToAdd = new int[currentIndex - initialIndex - 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < currentIndex - initialIndex; i++) {
            arrayToAdd[i] = originalArray[initialIndex + i];
        }
        resultingList.add(arrayToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem with the previous code was that I was deleting the reference of arrayA object which was pointed by the elements of array p so the solution was just to initialize again the array instead of calling method clear

Comment: Okay, great that you got it!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you add your linked list into the final storage p, you are assuming the elements of the list are put in there.  Only a pointer is referenced, so when you clear it the next line, all the elements are gone.

```
p.add((LinkedList) arrayA);
arrayA.clear();
```

One tip is to move arrayA's scope to inside the function.  This is because it's temporary, and only a sublist, so it shouldn't be at the instance level.  It can be reused by doing a

```
arrayA = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

and when doing so, you haven't lost the old list because p is keeping a reference to it.

Another tip is to name your lists with meaningful names.

originalIntList, groupedIntList, singleGroupIntList help the reader figure out what they could be doing more than a comment stating obvious aspects of the Java object.

Comment: yes that was the problem with the code and the fix was really simple next time I will consider to write meaningful names for the code